# jQuery change data attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have the folowing HTML element :

```
<li class="total_payment" data-basetotal="0.00">
    <span>
        <h5>Total</h5>
    </span>
</li>
```

I want to change the data-basetotal value from 0.00 to 50.00 with jQuery jQuery v1.7.2 using :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.total_payment').attr('data-basetotal', '50.00');
});
```

but it is not working , how can I change the value please?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like that class should be an id if its unique which appears to be.

Comment: That should work as written, can you reproduce the failure? And define what "*not working*" means in the context of your question.

Comment: [It works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/69ftvobu/)

Answer (score 5):

Try to use

```
$('.total_payment').data('basetotal', '50.00');
```

Comment: This is the preferred way of handling `data` attributes. As a note though, this won't actually change the `data-basetotal` attribute on the element; it will only modify the jQuery data object associated with that element.